# Modified h1 font size

Tags: css, typography

I am confused as to why these two h1 tags have different font sizes, when obviously they contain identical properties/declarations.  To what little knowledge I do possess, I feel It has something to do with inheritance; seeing how one h1 tag is nested and the other is not.
HTML:

```
 <div id="site-offline-container">
        <div id="site-offline-heading">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

   <h1 class="hello">Hello World</h1>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background:#fff;
  font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px; letter-spacing:1px; color:#000;
}
#site-offline-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing:-5px;
  color:#000;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 1px 1px;
}
#site-offline-heading h1 {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.hello {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing:-5px;
  color:#000;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 1px 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#site-offline-heading h1` is telling the css to style all h1 headings inside the element with the id site-offline-heading

Your other h1 is outside this element and so uses the default styling for h1, if you want to apply the same style to all your h1 tags use this: `h1{/*styling*/}`

Comment: Both #site-offline-heading and .hello both have the same styles but the font size still shows up differently on the page, simply because one of the h1 tags is nested.  I wanted to know why that was. and #site-offline-heading h1 just has a margin: bottom rule applied to it, no styles.

Comment: It's because h1 (set to its default setting by your browser) is more specific than the div it's contained in.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting font size on an element containing an h1 in the first case, directly on an h1 element in the second. This makes a difference, since in the first case h1 takes its default font size, 200%, i.e. twice the font size of its container (parent).

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you are saying.  I'm also not understanding why the first h1 tag ( that is nested ) is bigger than the h1 tag that is not.

Comment: The first `h1` gets the font size 80px (2 times 40px), since by default `h1` font size is 2 times its parent's font size. The second `h1` simply gets font size 40px because you set it so.